# "Blinking" animation in Python with libavg

Tags: python, animation, libavg

I'm working on a project using libavg and a series of RectNodes. What I'm trying to do is play an animation that makes each node light up white for 2,5 seconds, and then fades back. Every time you click one of the nodes, the same animation should happen for that specific node.

I'm using the AVGApp class, and a list with RectNode id and how many times they are supposed to light up, like (id1, 2)

```
def playAnim(self, animarr):
        for i in range(0, len(animarr)):
            i, count = animarr[i]
            sid = "r" + str(i)
            node = g_player.getElementByID(sid)
            while count > 0:
                self.blink(node)
                count -= 1
        return
```

and my code for blink:

```
 def blink(self, node):
    pos = node.pos
    size = node.size

    covernode = avg.RectNode(pos=pos, size=size, fillopacity=0,
                             parent = self._parentNode, fillcolor="ffffff", 
                               color="000000", strokewidth=2)

    self.animObj = LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 0, 1)
    self.animObj.start()
    self.animObj = LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 1, 0)
    self.animObj.start()
    covernode.unlink(True)
    return
```

I'm calling it with:

```
def _enter(self):
    (some other stuff here)

    print "Let's get started!"
    self.playAnim(self.animArr)
    print "Your turn!"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, the libavg Reference isn't helping me much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that anim.start() is non-blocking.
Instead of only returning after the animation is finished, it will return immediately and the animation will be executed concurrently. This means at the same time your function starts two animations **and** unlinks the node that should be animated.

So instead you should use the end callbacks that can be given to the animations to trigger one step after another. The the blink function could then look like this:

```
def blink(self, node):
    pos = node.pos
    size = node.size    
    covernode = avg.RectNode(pos=pos, size=size, fillopacity=0,
                             parent = self._parentNode, fillcolor="ffffff", 
                             color="000000", strokewidth=2)

    fadeOutAnim = LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 1, 0, False, 
                             None, covernode.unlink)
    fadInAnim= LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 0, 1, False,
                              None, fadeOutAnim.start)
    fadInAnim.start()
```

If you want the node to stay white for a certain amount of time you have to insert another step using either a WaitAnim or player.setTimeout().
(https://www.libavg.de/reference/current/player.html#libavg.avg.Player)

```
def blink(self, node):
    pos = node.pos
    size = node.size    
    covernode = avg.RectNode(pos=pos, size=size, fillopacity=0,
                             parent = self._parentNode, fillcolor="ffffff", 
                             color="000000", strokewidth=2)

    fadeOutAnim = LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 1, 0, False, 
                             None, covernode.unlink
                             )
    fadInAnimObj = LinearAnim(covernode, 'fillopacity', 1000, 0, 1, False,
                              None, lambda:self.wait(500, fadeOutAnim.start)
                              )
    fadInAnimObj.start()


def wait(self, time, end_cb):
    avg.Player.get().setTimeout(time, end_cb)
```